# Register for incoming calls with application endpoint (UCMA)

Tags: c#, lync, ucma

I have created a trust application, which have sip:you@domain.com as endpoint contact. I'm using the UCMASampleHelper from the UCMA SDK to create and establish my app endpoint, which seems to work without any exceptions.

But when I'm doing

```
applicationEndpoint.RegisterForIncomingCall<AudioVideoCall>(AVCallReceived);
```

running the application in debug, and trying to call the sip address, the AVCallReceived isn't fired.

Anyone that can tell me what's going wrong?? Lync client is trying to place a call, but the event is never fired.

EDIT: Here is a code sample http://pastebin.com/wyHAhQuU

Comment: It is hard to answer the question without looking at the code. Perhaps, the SIP INVITE not reaching your endpoint at all? If possible, try VoiceXMLSample from SDK/Core/Sample Applications/QuickStarts.

Comment: Here is a code sample http://pastebin.com/wyHAhQuU. Can't WS to trace for SIP INVITE msg's, since all Lync communication is TLS of cause. I ain't receiveing any of the RegisterForIncomingCall events, which I don't understand. When I'm creating my appEndpoint the _applicationContactURI is sip:myuser@domain.com. I'm trying to make a Lync call from my lync client to this sip:myuser@domain.com, but no call event is received...

Comment: Any one that have a solution? I have seen through the ContactCenter sample in UCMA too, which does use RegisterForIncomingCall<T>() on an ApplicationEndpoint. But when I'm trying to call the lync user I use to create the ApplcationEndpoint, I'm getting told that the user seems to be offline, tho my app is running in the background...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Creating a UserEndpoint with the ApplicationEndpoint sip uri passed in the constructor, and then register for calls on the UserEndpoint object.